# Unexpected results with PATINDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, pattern-matching, matching

I am working on some string manipulation with PATINDEX to fix some incorrect time formatting in XML e.g. (2018-12-20T17:00:00-05:00).

The issue I am having is PATINDEX is finding a match to @Pattern in the @IncorrectMatchIndex string.

You can recreate the issue by running the following:

```
DECLARE @Pattern nvarchar(36) = '%<EstmatedTime>%T%-%</EstmatedTime>%',
        @CorrectMatchIndex nvarchar(100) = '<DiscountedRate>263.34</DiscountedRate><EstmatedTime>2018-12-20T17:00:00-05:00</EstmatedTime></Rate>',
        @CorrectMatchIndex2 nvarchar(94) = '<DiscountedRate>263.34</DiscountedRate><EstmatedTime>2018-12-20T17:00:00</EstmatedTime></Rate>',
        @IncorrectMatchIndex nvarchar(296) = '<DiscountedRate>263.34</DiscountedRate><EstmatedTime>2018-12-20T17:00:00</EstmatedTime></Rate><Rate><Carrier>FedEx Freight</Carrier><Service>FEDEX_FREIGHT_PRIORITY</Service><PublishedRate>520.6</PublishedRate><DiscountedRate>272.04</DiscountedRate><EstmatedTime>2018-12-18T17:00:00</EstmatedTime>'

SELECT
  PATINDEX(@Pattern, @CorrectMatchIndex) AS CorrectMatchIndex,
  PATINDEX(@Pattern, @CorrectMatchIndex2) AS CorrectMatchIndex2,
  PATINDEX(@Pattern, @IncorrectMatchIndex) AS IncorrectMatchIndex
```

Comment: If you have a long term need for such work, then consider using a proper XML parser.  `PATINDEX` will fall short quickly I think.

Comment: All of those results look correct to me. Why do you believe they are wrong?

Comment: I agree with Tim. SQL Server has native XML data types, XQuery and XPath support, don't use PATINDEX for this.

Comment: The @IncorrectMatchIndex string does not contain a match to '%<EstmatedTime>%T%-%</EstmatedTime>%' as far as I can see.  There is no dash between the T and closing </EstmatedTime> tag.

Comment: @AlecThomas , Yes it does. `'<EstmatedTime>` is at position 40. You have a `'T'` after that in the following time. Then you have have both a hyhpen (`-`) and `'</EstmatedTime>'` at the end of the string (`'2018-12-18T17:00:00</EstmatedTime>'`) The value returned (40) is correct, as that's where that matching string starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a pure guess, I suspect you want:

```
DECLARE @Pattern nvarchar(300) = '%<EstmatedTime>[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]T[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]</EstmatedTime>%'
```

This then returns `0` for `IncorrectMatchIndex`.

Of course, the comments are right, you should really be using XQUERY for this. I can't provide a sample for this, however, as none of the XML data you have supplied it valid XML (for example `@CorrectMatchIndex` ends with `'</Rate>'` but that node is never opened).

Comment: Yea, for simplification I didn't copy over the entire XML for this example.  Thanks for the help, I will consider XQUERY per your guys suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

> The @IncorrectMatchIndex string does not contain a match to `%<EstmatedTime>%T%-%</EstmatedTime>%` as far as I can see. There is no dash between the T and closing `</EstmatedTime>`

Yes there is.   Because there is a second set of `<EstimatedTime>` tags later in the string, and there most certainly is a '-' character between the *first* `T` and the *last* `</EstimatedTime>`